# Data files for Quickly apps

Tags: application-development, python, quickly

My Quickly app requires data files to store settings, configuration and etc.  How would I do this inside the app folder.  Keep in mind that I will need to read and write to these files while the app is running on a client's computer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has more to do with general application development than Quickly. Have a look at your home folder and press ctrl+h or the equivalent to show hidden files in your file manager.

Applications who need to store usersettings do this by creating a hidden folder (prefixed with a dot) and write the configuration files there. Other stuff like a database, extra plugins etc can be put here too.

This has to be done in the code at runtime, not during installion. Something like this should be enough:

```
import os
confdir = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), '.myapp')
conffile = os.path.join(confdir, 'myapp.conf')
if not os.path.exists(confdir):
    os.makedirs(confdir)
    with open(conffile, 'w') as f:
        f.write('This is the default config')
```

Have a look at the [ConfigParser](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html#module-ConfigParser) or [JSON](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html#module-json) module to work with a configuration format.

Comment: Two questions.  How would I write to this file and read from it?  Why do you not check if the conffile exists?

Comment: Reading and writing is just standard Python: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: If the confdir doesn't exist yet, then the conffile won't either. If the confdir does exist, your program already created a conffile. You could do some extra checks etc, this is just a basic example.

Comment: OK, now what I don't understand is how to make that os.path thing work with standard python open()

Comment: I edited my answer with some more details. This is just very simple Python though, maybe it's not a bad idea to read the tutorial first. http://docs.python.org/tutorial/index.html